# Xamarin Forms Redraw StackLayout on Device Orientation Change

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

In my **MainPage.xaml**, which is a **ContentPage**, I have a **GradientColorStack**.

```
<local:GradientColorStack x:Name="ColorStack" StartColor="#FF0000" EndColor="#FFFF00">
```

This class has **StackLayout** as a base class and it presents a background that has a gradient color fill. I got this idea from [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/horizontal-and-vertical-gradient-color-in-xamarin-forms/).

```
public class GradientColorStack : StackLayout
```

The problem is that on device orientation change, the background color fill is not re-drawn. Thus in landscape orientation there is a big gap filled with black where you can see through the GradientColorStack to the ContentPage background.

Is there a way to force the GradientColorStack to re-draw on device orientation change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**iOS Version**

I added the following method to my renderer class:

```
protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    SetNeedsDisplay();
    base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
}
```

This causes the `Draw()` method of the same class to be called on a screen orientation event. In `Draw()` I now find the existing **CAGradientLayer** (if it exists) and remove it from the super layer and then just let the `Draw()` routine then calculate a new **CAGradientLayer** as usual, which it then adds to the NativeView.Layer.Sublayers collection as usual.

Thanks to @SHUBHAM SHARMA for the tip of using `SetNeedsDisplay()` but [this post](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/324735/#Comment_324735) was also required to get the solution working.

---

**Android Version**

It turns out the Android version was already working to correctly redraw the gradient layer (see [tutorial](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/horizontal-and-vertical-gradient-color-in-xamarin-forms/)). I think this is because of the following method in my renderer class:

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<StackLayout> e)
{
    base.OnElementChanged(e);

    if (e.OldElement != null || Element == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    var stack = e.NewElement as GradientColorStack;
    this.StartColor = stack.StartColor;
    this.EndColor = stack.EndColor;
}
```

Comment: Note that the `OnElementPropertyChanged` code here is calling `SetNeedsDisplay` on *any* property change. For a complex display running on a slow device, *might* want to put a breakpoint in the method, find out what `e.PropertyName` is sent in (there may be multiple ones triggered while rotating phone, not sure), and pick a single property to do SetNeedsDisplay. `if (e.PropertyName == ...) SetNeedsDisplay();` I'm not sure this matters - maybe will only be one re-layout regardless - just mentioning in case it might help be more performant when rotate. Or avoid unnecessary redraw other times.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **ForceLayout()** in **android** Renderer and **SetNeedDisplay()** in **iOS** Renderer because these function are forcefully refresh the layout.

Comment: Ok, but what method or event handler in the renderer do I use to call those? Both iOS and Android are  GradientColorStackRenderer : VisualElementRenderer<StackLayout>

Comment: you can use when the orientation of device is alter, like in iOS on ViewDidLoad() and in anroid you have to create delegate and write forclayout() your instant and invoke that on OnConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) function on mainActivity.

Comment: Sorry, this information is not specific enough for me to work with. For example, I tried adding ViewDidLoad() to my iOS GradientColorStackRenderer class and got GradientColorStackRenderer.cs(30,30): Error CS0115: 'GradientColorStackRenderer.ViewDidLoad()': no suitable method found to override (CS0115) (MyProject.iOS)